# Reading methods from a text file for Java

Tags: java, text-files

I am working on an assignment and was wondering how one can read a method with  a parameter stated in a text file. For example, in my assignment the addFirst method will have a string right after it (addFirst New York). Also, The addFirst method name may be all lowercase. I've been looking around the net and this is what I already worked on:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Assignment2 {

  static DequeUsingStacks<String> deq = new DequeUsingStacks<String>();

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{    
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("Assignment2.txt");   
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        String m;

        while((m = br.readLine()) != null){

                if(m.equalsIgnoreCase("size"))
                    System.out.println(deq.size());

                if(m.equalsIgnoreCase("addFirst")) /*I want to be able to 
                                                     use the string after 
                                                     the method as the new 
                                                     Value. So new 
                                                     Value should equal to 
                                                    "New York"*/

                deq.addFirst(new value);

        }

        fstream.close();
```

DequeUsingStacks is another class with all the methods. I guess I just want to know how to read a line in a textfile with multiple strings. "New Value" is the string stated after the method in the text file. For example, (addFirst New York), the string "New York" should be the "New Value". I'm thinking that the line read should be put into an array. But I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Perhaps you should try asking for help form the person that gave you the assignment...?

Comment: If you know the method name you can try this....  if(m.contains("addFirst")) {
             
                  deq.addFirst(m.replaceAll("addFirst", "").trim());
                 }

Comment: It is currently not possible to understand what you are asking as you have omitted too much context.  What is `deq`? What do you mean by _new value_?  The code you have shown is very far from being compilable.  Please consider writing a [mcve] and [edit]ing your post to clarify it.

Comment: Hi Java, Thanks for the help. I forgot to mention that that the method name might not be exactly addFirst, it could be all lowercase letters. Which is why I used .equalsIgnoreCase(). I like the idea of using replaceAll() but does the parameter have to be exactly "addFirst" for it to work? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry Jim, I am new to this site so I am not fully aware of how everything works. I will update the code as best i can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is a way

```
   if ( m.toLowerCase().indexOf("addFirst".toLowerCase()) != -1 ) {
        deq.addFirst(m.replaceAll("addFirst".toLowerCase(), "").trim());
        }
```

assign your method name to a **string** and use it for checking instead of hard coding as "addFirst".

Comment: Thank you very much. I was looking at  other ways for the equalsIgnoreCase() and only found out about .toLowerCase(). This was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

i think you may try

```
if(m.contains("addFirst")) { 

  String[] words = m.split("addFirst"); // In this case assume that do not have any others sentences after word "New York"
String result = words.get(0);

deq.addFirst(result);

}
```